# heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones

Tags: animation, rigging

I have the model of a man formed by jacket, trousers, shoes, hands and head, all joined with CTRL J.
When I go to create the armor he gives me "heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones". I tried to apply the scale, rotation, and location but nothing. I tried to remove doubles but nothing, and I even deleted a lot of faces, vertices and edges. I don't know what to do anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Switch back to spare parts and parent them to the rig one by one, the automatic weights function wants a single mesh, with a mesh maden of multiple parts sometimes it works, more often not.

Consider also that manual weighting is often the best choice (weight painting and/or weight assigning in the vertex properties panel).